# Azure Data Factory: Data Flow, JSON Keys with Curly Braces in them

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have to parse thousands of JSON files with a particular structure, see below. The challenge is that Azure Data Flow seems to consider { } as references to keys, and despite my fields being filled, I get NULLs

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://longurllink",
    "value": [{
            "@odata.etag": "\"2\"",
            "ItemInternalId": "27708",
            "ID": 27708,
            "Modified": "2022-11-24T15:11:27Z",
            "{Identifier}": "Recordings%252thismyrecording.wma",
            "{IsFolder}": false,
..., { more entries}]
```

With an Azure Data Flow, I can simply flatten using Value as unroll, obtaining individual IDs and Modified. But the JSON keys with a { } in their name are always NULL. I suspect this is because Data Flow treats { } as references, and hence turns them into 'value.Identifier' for which there is no value.

I cannot change the original JSON fields.

I originally started with just a copy activity for JSON with a mapping, but couldn't get the right fields.

I have tried to stringify the json, replace { } within keys with nothing, and then reparse them as JSON in Data Flow, but that has not yet been succesfull. Is it even possible in ADF?

I have also tried other means of references such as value.{{Identifier}} or {value.{Identifier}} but they either are not permitted ("Unknown column") or return NULLs as well.

When I look up for how to escape such characters, I get countless examples of other escape characters. I simply want to escape the column name in Data Flow itself.

I'm starting to feel obliged to start up a whole Custom script just to handle these pesky curly braces, but surely there must be some solution in Data Factory itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with following JSON.

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"2\"",
            "ItemInternalId": "27708",
            "ID": 27708,
            "Name": "Rakesh",
            "{Identifier}":"Recordings%252thismyrecording.wma",
            "{IsFolder}": false,
            "{Marks}":24
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"3\"",
            "ItemInternalId": "27709",
            "ID": 27709,
            "Name": "Laddu",
            "{Identifier}": "Recordings%2426thismyrecording.wma",
            "{IsFolder}": true,
            "{Marks}":26
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"3\"",
            "ItemInternalId": "27710",
            "ID": 27710,
            "Name": "Virat",
            "{Identifier}": "Recordings%183thismyrecording.wma",
            "{IsFolder}": false,
            "{Marks}":16
        }
    ]
}
```

If you take the schema from the dataset, due to the `@` in the column name, ADF pipeline is giving bad request error while debugging. So, clear the schema from the dataset.

[image]

So, I took the schema from the `import projection` in the Dataflow source.

I have flattened the array like below.

[image]

I faced same issue as yours, you can see it is giving null values after flattening the array.

[image]

Also, you can see It is showing more columns than `5`(Flatten transformation showing 5).

But when I executed this dataflow from pipeline after adding the sink, it is giving the expected values from flattening in the sink file.

[image]

So, it is showing the null values and less columns only during the data preview of the dataflow but after the pipeline execution it is giving expected output.

As you mentioned, dataflow treating `{}` as references might be the reason for it or it might be a bug as well.

As your schema is same for every JSON file, it will take the schema from the file not from the dataset and it will give the flattened data in sink files.

Comment: Thank you. If preview differs from result, then they ought to change that. It would be nice if there was some escape chars as well for {}.